# How can a $k\times (k-m)$ matrix be multiplied by a $k\times m$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

While reading a book on differential geometry, I came across this line:

> Since the differential $d\psi_0(x_0):\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^k$ is injective, there is a matrix $B\in \mathbb R^{k\times (k-m)}$ such that $$det(d\psi_0(x_0)B)\neq 0$$. My question is: How can a $k\times m$ matrix be multiplied by a $k\times (k-m)$ matrix? What does the author actually want to say? And how can we prove the theorem he used?

Comment: You use two different ways for the multiplication of the matrices. Note that matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: This is really strange. We would need $m=k$, but then we would have a $k\times 0$-matrix.

Comment: Seems to be a typo.

Comment: @Peter I'm definitely with you. But what does he actually want to say?

Comment: @Peter By the way, why do we need $m=k$?

Comment: A $a\times b$-matrix can only be multiplied with a $c\times d$-matrix, if $b=c$.

Comment: As stated, the only thing that makes sense is that the author wants to form the block matrix $(d\psi | B)$, which would be a $k\times k$ matrix. Then it is true that if $d\psi$ is injective, there exists some $B$ to complete it to a square matrix such that that matrix is invertible.

Comment: A more common thing to do would be to use a map $A: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and compose $A \circ d\psi$. Perhaps this is what was intended, but then there are several typos.

Comment: @aes How to show that if $d\psi$ is injective, then there exists $B$ to complete it and form an invertible matrix?

Comment: @pxc3110 John Hughes has a nice answer below. The point is you can always complete linearly independent vectors (the columns of $d\psi$) to a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Revised on the basis of pxc3110's comment:)

The author probably wants to say that 
$$
det((d\psi_0(x_0)|B))\neq 0\
$$
where the $(P|Q)$ notation means "take the $k \times m$ matrix $A = d\psi_0(x_0)$ and append to it $m-k$ more columns, i.e., an $k \times (m-k)$ matrix $B$ to get an invertible matrix.

Here's the reason you can do that. The matrix $A$ has rank $m$ because the map's injective. Its columns $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ are therefore $m$ *independent* vectors in $\mathbb R^k$. We can therefore extend these to a basis of $\mathbb R^k$ by including $m-k$ more $k$-vectors $c_1, \ldots, c_{m-k}$, which when laminated together give a matrix $B$ of size $k \times (m-k)$.

One of my favorite ways to find these remaining vectors is to take the vectors 
$$
a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m, e_1, \ldots, e_k
$$
(where the $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors) and perform the Gram-Schmidt operation on them, with the additional rule that if at any time you get a zero vector, you eliminate it from consideration. The result will always be a basis, because (1) After $p$ steps of GS, you have vectors whose span is the same as that of the first $p$ vectors. (2) Eliminating a zero-vector doesn't change the span, and (3) after $m+k$ steps, you include the span of all the $e_i$s, which is the whole space.

Yeah, it's overkill...but it's dead simple. :)

Comment: Fixed. Thanks much. I'm embarrassed to say that I double-checked that before posting. :(

Comment: @JohnHughes I think the author wanted to say that B and $d\psi_0(x_0)$ can be put together and form an invertible square matrix